# Tee function call in C doesn't work and not tee command

Tags: c, linux, shell, tee

Hi i have been writing a linux shell in C. I want to redirect my output to both file and terminal and I found tee is the way to go. I went to linux man page of tee and found that tee can be used as function call to invoke within C program. 
So i wrote

```
int size =tee(pipeends[1], 1,INT_MAX,SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK);
```

But this simply doesn't work. it says

> implicit declaration of function ‘tee’
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>        size =tee(pipeends[1], 1,INT_MAX,SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK);

I have searched a lot in the internet and everything that it returns is how to use tee command in terminal which I know is by using tee . But I want to code it in program and not let user input it explicitly.
I have added header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include< fcntl.h>
```

as part of my linux shell code. I dont know if tee uses some other header files or not but I'm clueless.

Comment: Since the man page shows the header to include (and you did that), you can always open than header file and just look for the declaration of `tee`. Presumably you'll find it guarded by the `#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE` macro the page also mentions.

Comment: this statement: `#include< fcntl.h>` has the wrong syntax.  Do not place a space inside the `<` and `>`

Answer (score 4):

[The manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html) gives the necessary steps:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <fcntl.h>
```

This will bring in a declaration, which is:

```
ssize_t tee(int fd_in, int fd_out, size_t len, unsigned int flags);
```

So you should be able to write a program to set up a tee based on that information. Do note that the call is Linux-specific, this is not a standard C (nor POSIX, the Unix standard that Linux often complies with) function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't included the right headers in your file:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <fcntl.h>
```

You didn't mention `_GNU_SOURCE` in your question.  Maybe you need that?

Answer (score 0):

Include these:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
ssize_t tee(int fd_in, int fd_out, size_t len, unsigned int flags);`
```

The third line is the one which would remove that warning.(It did for me )

Also, If you're going to use splice() after tee, use these following macros:

```
ssize_t splice(int fd_in, loff_t *off_in, int fd_out, loff_t *off_out, size_t len, unsigned int flags);

#ifndef SPLICE_F_MOVE
#define SPLICE_F_MOVE           0x01
#endif
#ifndef SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK
#define SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK       0x02
#endif
#ifndef SPLICE_F_MORE
#define SPLICE_F_MORE           0x04
#endif
#ifndef SPLICE_F_GIFT
#define SPLICE_F_GIFT           0x08
#endif
```

Hope it helped. I know that the deadline is over now :(